# Bash: stop on error in sourced script

Tags: bash, shell

In a shell script to be executed, I can abort on errors using `set -e`.

In a sourced script, however, using `set -e` will kill the original shell if a later command exits with an error status.

```
source set_e.sh
./exit_1.sh
# shell dies
```

A trivial solution would be to `set +e` at the end of the script, but this would break the parent's `set -e` if used (which may very well happen if someone wraps my script in the future).

How can I get abort-on-error functionality in a sourced script?

Comment: @BlueMoon OP's post explains why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Couldn't you set an exit trap in the calling environment and handle it there?

Answer (score 9):

It's impossible. However you can opt to use a subshell if you want:

```
(
    set -e
    source another.sh
)
```

Only that environment of calling script can never be altered by the called script.

Note: It may be important to separate both commands with newline and not use a semicolon.

Comment: I thought this was a good idea, but apparently the stdout & stderr of the subshell are not propagated to the outside :/

Comment: @xeruf try [mkfifo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html)

Answer (score 5):

Well, the question is not very clear re: what the original author wanted after intercepting the error in the sourced script, however, as an entry point for the solution the following will suffice:

You can set a trap on ERR and handle the error inside the sourced script there.  Below are two scenarios: one with the sourced script using "set -e" and another with the sourced script NOT using "set -e".

**The primary script is calling the secondary script with defined "set -e" and catches an error:**

```
[galaxy => ~]$ cat primary.sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e
echo 'Primary script'
trap 'echo "Got an error from the secondary script"' ERR
source secondary.sh
trap - ERR
echo 'Primary script exiting'
[galaxy => ~]$ cat secondary.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Secondary script'
set -e
echo 'Secondary script generating an error'
false
echo 'Secondary script - should not be reached'
[galaxy => ~]$ ./primary.sh
Primary script
Secondary script
Secondary script generating an error
Got an error from the secondary script
[galaxy => ~]$
```

**The primary script is calling the secondary script without "set -e" and catches an error:**

```
[galaxy => ~]$ cat primary.sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e
echo 'Primary script'
trap 'echo "Got an error from the secondary script"' ERR
source secondary.sh
trap - ERR
echo 'Primary script exiting'
[galaxy => ~]$ cat secondary.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Secondary script'
echo 'Secondary script generating an error'
false
echo 'Secondary script - should not be reached if sourced by primary.sh'
[galaxy => ~]$ ./primary.sh
Primary script
Secondary script
Secondary script generating an error
Got an error from the secondary script
[galaxy => ~]$
```

**As a bonus: intercepting an error in the sourced script and continuing:**

```
[galaxy => ~]$ cat primary.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Primary script'
i=0
while [ $i = 0 ]; do
    i=1
    trap 'echo "Got an error from the secondary script"; break' ERR
    source secondary.sh
done
trap - ERR
echo 'Primary script exiting'
[galaxy => ~]$ cat secondary.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Secondary script'
echo 'Secondary script generating an error'
false
echo 'Secondary script - should not be reached if sourced by primary.sh'
[galaxy => ~]$ ./primary.sh
Primary script
Secondary script
Secondary script generating an error
Got an error from the secondary script
Primary script exiting
[galaxy => ~]$
```

Comment: I believe the trap with the break only works if the secondary script doesn't have a while, for, or until in it. is that true?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, @kdubs.  The point was to demonstrate the concept though.

Comment: that's fine, I just wanted to make sure I under stood.

Answer (score 4):

Change `set -e` to `return 0` (or choose your favorite integer instead of `0`). You can think of it as treating your sourced file as a function. For example:

```
$ cat myreturn.sh
#!/bin/bash

let i=0

while test "$i" -lt 10; do

    echo "i $i"
    if test "$i" -gt 5 ; then
        return 5
    fi
    sleep 1
    ((i+=1))

done

return 4

$ ( . myreturn.sh )
i 0
i 1
i 2
i 3
i 4
i 5
i 6

$ echo $?
5
```

Comment: 1) you shouldn't choose some random integer as exit code - 0 means success, everything else not - and ideally they have some meaning 2) this doesn't answer the question because "return 0" doesn't help you catch an error in a script you don't control.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `set -e` is already enabled and conditionally set it afterwards:

```
[[ $- == *e* ]] && state=-e || state=+e
set -e
yourcode
set "$state"
```

Note, however, that `set -e` is buggy and scripts should never depend on it for correctness.  For example, if someone sources your script in an `if` statement, `set -e` may no longer work correctly:

```
echo '
 set -e
 ls file.that.doesnt.exist
 echo "Success"
' > yourscript

set -e
if ! source yourscript
then 
  echo "Initialization failed"
fi
echo "Done"
```

then `set -e` will longer abort on failure in `yourscript` in bash 4.3.30:

```
ls: cannot access file.that.doesnt.exist: No such file or directory
Success
Done
```

while it will exit the entire script in bash 2, 3 and up to 4.2:

```
ls: cannot access file.that.doesnt.exist: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The second part is misleading - if `yourscript` sets `errexit`, the wrapper code will indeed abort on errors inside it (tested with bash 4.2.x). This may seem counter-intuitive compared to the regular usage of shell if-then-else, but if you're sourcing unreliable code, the expectation that you'll wrap it in a subshell doesn't seem at all unreasonable.

Comment: @JosipRodin I see that bash 2 and 3 aborted the entire script, but on 4.3.30(1)-release it fails to abort as described. Interesting to know that the behavior has changed so much.

Comment: Good catch. I think the current behavior is consistent with the main advice - to use a subshell. For example, if you do: `set +e; ( . yourscript ); if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "Initialization failed"; fi` - the result is fairly logical.

Comment: Surely the point of sourcing is specifically that it doesn't create a subshell, otherwise you could just run it normally.

Comment: I think the issue might be that you're expecting it to run in the same context as the parent script (in a preprocessor `#include` fashion) while at the same time running it within an `if` in that script. The latter action is known to modify the context in such a way to make `errexit` void. So modifying the behavior of `source` there is par for the course.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - regardless of where you unset "e" after the script, if there is some error in the sourced script the parent shell will be killed as long as `set -e` is set...

Answer (score 2):

Setting, catching and unsetting `set -e` turned out rather fragile for me.
Thus I prefer trapping for errors.

This is a one-liner I often use, including trying a silenced `return` (works if sourced), otherwise `exit`. Also, unsetting the trap, since otherwise that one stays around from sourced scripts.

`trap 'echo Error $? on line $LINENO; trap - ERR; return 2>/dev/null || exit' ERR`

Answer (score 0):

You could detect by `set -o` if the errexit option was set at the beginning of the sourced script and recover its original value at the end of the sourced script.